# Дистрибутив linux для языков С, С++, Python

Tags: c++, linux

Хочу расширить свои навыки как программиста в направлении кроссплатформенности. Хочу изучить создание приложений на линуксе, использование линуксовского WinApi, но не знаю какой дистрибутив лучше всего выбрать. Расскажите какой дистрибутив выбрать? Мне советовали mint, но хотелось бы услышать и других людей.

Comment: **линуксовского WinApi** - это круто...

Comment: ` линуксовского WinApi` это оксюморон. Советую начать с чтения учебников по операционным системам. Почитать книги Андрея Столярова. Они совершенно бесплатны. Не самое лучшее учебное пособие, но даст вектор, куда копать дальше.

Comment: Ага, не думал что этот оксюморон будет кому-нить непонятен. Но все же, хотелось бы и книжку читать, и параллельно писать программы под линем.

Comment: Идем на [дистровотч](https://distrowatch.com/), выбираем среди популярных, ставим, добавляем нужные пакеты (cmake, ..., python). Вообще, многие сделаны на основе либо Дебиана, либо RedHat (Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Fedora, Centos). Или BSD, но это уже не GNU Linux. Я за дебиан.

Comment: Я не буду мучатся в попытках что-либо настроить в дебиане? Просто я слышал что он не простой совсем

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый будешь. Например, дрова на вайфай скорее всего не станут из коробки. Не хочешь мучиться, поставь убунту. Если винда более привычна для использования, ставь минт с корицей. Хочешь ада и ритуальных танцев - генту. Там, на самом деле, на любой характер, темперамент и ориентацию есть дистрибутивы. Но, имхо, минт, как самый простой и понятный. Ставится за 10 минут, настраивать ничего не надо. После инстала накатил всё для компиляции и учись.

Comment: Да фигня. Любой дистр. Версию бери testing или предрелизную. Дрова все есть, только надо докинуть всякое firmware.

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы. Мой выбор пал на Linux Mint последней версии с cinnamon

Answer (score -1):

Рекомендую Debian 10 Buster. На данный момент почти стабилен и поддерживает современное железо. В дистрибутиве современные версии компиляторов и питона.

Не Убунтоиды потому что там занимаешься обновлением, а не делом.

Выбирайте мэйнстрим Gnome 3 или Plasma. Первый хорош для приложений на питоне и голом си, второй для c++ (qt) и более кроссплатформенный в целом.